# Force property to null

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I assume the following would set the destination to `null`, but it doesn't. What's wrong?

```
.ForMember(m => m.prop1, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyType>(src => null))
```

Comment: Try setting AllowNullDestinationValues to true.

Comment: This is deprecated it seems

Comment: I don't know what gave you that idea, but no :)

Comment: Ah found it in the global configs, but doesn't make a difference. I create mappings via `new MapperConfiguration` to inject via DI

Comment: Btw `UseValue(null)` it works for strings, but not for complex types

Comment: Can it be that `prop1` is initialized in the constructor of the destination object?

Comment: It works for me with the latest. Upgrade or try some other way. Ignore maybe?

Comment: Debugging shows the property is instantiated by Automapper. The class is created just before by myself. Solving it via manual null-setting for now...

Answer (score 1):

To set a certain fixed value, use `UseValue`. Note that the fixed value will be set once on configuration.

```
.ForMember(m => m.prop1, opt => opt.UseValue(null))
```

See also [Understanding UseValue in AutoMapper](https://julianwalls.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/understanding-usevalue-in-automapper/).

Comment: That's what I do, but seems to be only working for strings, not for classes etc. I always get an instantiated object.

Comment: Hm now that you mention it I only used `UseValue` with enums and strings.